# Android AVD manager does not working on Windows 10

Tags: android, android-studio, windows-10, android-virtual-device

OS: Windows 10
I installing Android Studio 2.1 (with AVD). But when i launch Android Studio i have disabled AVD manager start icon. I have right ANDROID_HOME value and Path value for directories ./tools and ./platform-tools.

Why AVD manager not working?

Comment: Where did you install your Studio and AVD?

Comment: Have you installed it using Android SDK manager?

Comment: So, i find solution. In my first install of Android Studio AVD installing is incorrect, but in next installisations, Android Studio loaded AVD config from tmp files. So i delete manually Android Studio tmp files from my user folder and reinstall it.